# How to store values in a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

Suppose you have the following recursive function. Assume the node argument is the head:

```
def to_string(node):
    a_str = ""

    if node.next != None:
        a_str += str(node.val)
        to_string(node.next)
    else:
        return a_str
```

I would like to record the value of all of the nodes. The code is able to obtain the values, since it is calling itself with the next node, `to_string(node.next)`, but it is not able to store the values and return the correct string since `a_str` is re-initialized upon every call. Is there a in-function solution to this, or will I have to rely on global variables?

Comment: Have you thought of passing params to approach this sort of problem in general?

Comment: @jamylak Yes, but this is a sample from a bigger project I am doing, so it has to stay in this form, unfortunately

Comment: In my mind, you can always add a additional default parameter to a function without haming the old. `def to_string(node, param="default")`. Just a a side note to jamylak's idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't returning a value in one case. Written properly, your function should look like this:

```
def to_string(node):
    a_str = str(node.val)
    if node.next != None:
        a_str += to_string(node.next)
    return a_str
```

Strings are immutable, so you don't need to initialize to anything other than the current node.

As to answer your question as to how to store things in a recursive function pythonically: you can use nested functions. A nested function can use a non-local variable in your main function scope to emulate a global without leaking anything out:

```
def to_string(node):
    def actual_recursive(node):
        nonlocal a_str
        a_str += str(node.val)
        if node.next != None:
            actual_recursive(node.next)
    a_str = ''
    actual_recursive(node)
    return a_str
```

The `nonlocal` keyword is a lot like `global`, but it lets you modify the value of the immediately surrounding function's scope.

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps that is a better approach - It should work in all recursive functions.

Comment: @Art. It's not. You end up reallocating the same number of times. The best option would probably not be recursive at all. I'd probably go with an iterator across the nodes, then `''.join(...)`